# Why I can't "run" a MSI file?

Tags: windows-installer, windows-shell

I have a file - node-v4.2.1-x86.msi
After double click on it, nothing happens.
I solved* this problem by running the command console, but the question remains - why I'm not able to run it in the normal way?

*solution:
msiexec /i node-v4.2.1-x86.msi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot really "run" anything except an executable (`.exe`, earlier also `.com`): when you "run" arbitrary file, "the shell"<sup>1</sup> kicks in and

1. Takes the extension of the file's name, looks up its table of associations to get *something* responsible for handling files with this extension;
2. Queries another table of such "somethings" to figure out how it should prepare the command line to call.
3. Formats the command line and then runs a process using it.

Let's take a nearby Windows XP, and query those two tables using `cmd.exe` and a bunch of standard commands `assoc` and `ftype`:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\kostix>assoc .msi
.msi=Msi.Package

C:\Documents and Settings\kostix>ftype Msi.Package
Msi.Package="%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "%1" %*
```

You should have something similar reported on your OS.

On recent Windows with improved Control Panel, you can open the Control Panel and search for the term "file associations" (but in your UI's language) to get the dialog which manages these file associations.

If any of this is missing or hosed, I'd say you have a problem with your setup.

---

<sup>1</sup> In Windows, that's Explorer — the program which presents you with the task bar, the desktop, the icons, the file browser windows etc, that is, basically provides the integration UI.

Comment: "file associations" that's the key. Thx!